# JavaScript solo imprime la ultima fila de un array bidimensional

Tags: javascript, array

Cordial saludo,

Compañeros espero que puedan ayudarme con el siguiente problema, tengo este código que básicamente lo que hace es solicitarle al usuario unos valores numéricos para llenar un array 3x4. El problema es que cuando recorro el array para mostrar los valores siempre me muestra los números de la ultima fila.

**Código:**

```js
var matriz = new Array(3,4);
var suma = 0;

for (f = 0; f < 3; f++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        matriz[f,c] = prompt("Ingrese un valor numerico para la fila #" + (f+1) + " y columna #" + (c+1) + ":", "");
        console.log(matriz[f,c])
    }
}

console.log("Valores de la matriz 3x4");
for (f = 0; f < 3; f++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        console.log("[" + matriz[f,c] + "] ");
    }
}

console.log("Suma de los elementos de cada fila");
for (f = 0; f < 3; f++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
    {
        suma+=parseInt(matriz[f,c]);
    }

    console.log("Suma fila #" + (f+1) + ": " + suma);
    suma = 0;
}

console.log("Suma de los elementos de cada columna");
for (c = 0; c < 4; c++)
{
    for (f = 0; f < 3; f++)
    {
        suma+=parseInt(matriz[f,c]);
    }

    console.log("Suma columna #" + (c+1) + ": " + suma);
    suma = 0;
}
```

**Resultado mostrado en la consola del navegador:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás creando un array con los valores [2] [10] [7] y [8].
Para corroborarlo podes hacer un console.log de matriz.

La forma para crear el array que necesitas sería matriz[x][x].

```
var x = new Array(3);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  x[i] = new Array(4);
}

console.log(x);
```

Espero que se entienda. Saludos!

Comment: Hola amigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Ya pude solucionar el problema. Saludos